# How do I delete a frame by attribute name

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 5 buttons that are initialized in individual frames, how do i go about deleting a frame that a user has specifically entered to delete the frame. So I'm looking to find out how to delete nested frames by user input. Reason is, i'm developing a card game that has a complex layout where frames will contain more than just buttons but want to destroy the frames depending on input.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

for y in range(0,5):
  frame = Frame(root,name = str(y))
  button = Button(frame,text=str(y))
  print(frame)
  frame.pack()
  button.pack()

entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()

def delete():
  buttonToDelete = int(entry.get())
  #What goes here to destroy the frame by user input have tried
  frame.name(buttonToDelete).destroy()

deleteButton = Button(root, text="Delete",command=delete)
deleteButton.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: If you read the console output, you will notice that the names of those frames are `.0`, `.1`, etc.  So you need to input it inside the entry and should not convert it to integer.  Then you can use `frame.nametowidget(buttonToDelete).destroy()` if content of `buttonToDelete` is something like `.0`.

Comment: Thanks @acw1668 its worked with your help of `buttonToDelete = "."+entry.get()` then 
`frame.nametowidget(buttonToDelete).destroy()`